# Prepend file names in shell

Tags: shell, shell-script

I have 100 .png files in a folder say test.png, example.png, etc.

I want to prepend them with `New_` so that it will be renamed as `New_test.png`, `New_example.png` etc.

How can I do it in shell.

Answer (score 3):

You didn't specify an operating system. This answer assumes Windows.

My first thought was a simple command such as

```
for %f in (*.png) do rename "%f" "New_%f"
```

But a file named `a.png` was first renamed to `New_a.png` and moved down the alphabetical order :-( The loop renamed this file a *second* time to New_New_a.png.

Therefore, this must be done in two steps:

```
dir /b *.png > png.txt
for /F %l in (png.txt) do rename "%l" "New_%l"
del png.txt
```

The first line creates a text file containing the names of all png files in the current directory. The second line parses each line of the file and renames the png's.